# How do I use WPA2 TKIP+AES or TKIP+CCMP on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: ubuntu, wifi

(Background: my Ubuntu laptop will only connect to my router at 54mbps, whereas my Chromebook connects at ~300mbps.)

On [a Gentoo thread](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-906922-start-0.html), I see:

> Thanks, I've changed from WPA2 TKIP to WPA2 CCMP + TKIP and now I have 802.11n connection

And:

> Couldn't be simpler. I only had to change my security setting from my previous "WPA2/TKIP" to "WPA2/TKIP+AES" in order to enable 802.11n.

So, how do I use those modes in Ubuntu?  `nm-applet` doesn't seem to make any mention of TKIP or AES.  `sudo wpa_cli status` shows:

```
Selected interface 'p2p-dev-wlp2s0'
wpa_state=DISCONNECTED
```

Do I need to create a `/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf`?

Comment: Try to set your router to WPA2/AES only